# Сервис массового определения параметров

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите с парсингом curl. Делаю небольшой сервис массового определения параметров тИЦ, pr, наличие в Dmoz, наличие в Яндекс каталоге. Я уже почти всё сделал, но не могу пропарсить яндес каталог, помогите с парсингом, как это сделать?

И ещё, как оптимизировать скрипт, сделать что бы он работал быстрее? И что сделать, чтобы меня не забанили за частые запросы?

P.s. я новичок, ещё плохо всё понимаю.

Comment: Какой язык?

Comment: Ну если curl, то cкорее всего своими экстрасенсорными способностями могу сказать, что PHP.

Comment: Да, забыл добавить что я делаю скрипт на php

Answer (score 1):

Для начала покажи код которым парсишь яндекс каталог, не писать же с нуля все регулярки тебе)
А чтоб не забанили прокси + привяжи антикапчу т.к яндекс начнет капчу выводить на частые запросы